# Custom plugin wont load my CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress plugin with custom JS and CSS. My codes adding the js file to the code perfectly, but not the CSS.
The CSS file is in the same folder as the plugin.
Heres how i'm attempting to load them in:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addjs' );
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'addCSS');

function addjs()
{
    wp_register_script( 'RegisterUser', plugins_url( 'RegisterUser.js', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'RegisterUser');

}
function addCSS() {
    wp_register_style( 'Cafe', plugins_url('Cafe.css'));
    wp_enqueue_style( 'Cafe' );
}
```

Comment: any reason why you're not adding the second parameter, `__FILE__`, in your css registration like you do with the JS?

Comment: And you're adding JS on frontend and CSS on backend, is that correct? Also, JS and CSS can be encoded within the same `*_enqueue_scripts`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `__FILE__` to CSS enqueue and using "admin" only loads files on admin pages. So unless you want that to happen you need to use same call as js files